# Failing to create 'geo_point' type in Python to Kibana

Tags: python, elasticsearch, kibana

I've been trying to get a Python dictionary to Kibana for some visualizations, but so far I've had no luck when it comes to the `geo_point`type.

I have a Python dicitonary that also comes with the key, value combination `{'geo': {'lat': 33, 'lon': 33}}` (among others) and I want to plot this in Kibana. So far I've tried to change the mapping type in my Python script and also in the Developer Tools in Kibana, but no luck. If you need any more information, feel free to ask.

Did not find a working answer to my question in other threads unfortunately.